# facing issue to get xpath

Tags: xpath

I am working on XPath script.I want xpath for the following tag.

```
  <td valign="top">   
    " Oct 17, 2011 "
   <br>
    " 3 Pages - Pub ID: KLI6673261"
```

I want xpath to get text after `<br>` tag.Means I want to fetch only [3 Pages - Pub ID: KLI6673261].Please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: the br element is not closed, it should be `<br />` to be valid XML, I doubt any XPath parser will be able to parse this kind of data. You should either clean it first or use other tools like regexp.

Comment: @jolivier my XPath parser will handle it fine. And I think any other parser that expects HTML (e.g. Firefox) will do as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all text following a `<br>` in a `<td>` like this:

```
/td/br/following-sibling::text()
```

Although if your xml/html doesn't auto close the `<br>`, it will think the text is inside the br, and you would need this

```
/td/br/text()
```